# Schedule Loadrunner Script to run nightly?

Tags: automation, schedule, loadrunner, nightly-build

My loadrunner script landscape is as follows: My tests are written in servlet, and i am using loadrunner scripts to trigger those servlets. 
Now i want to schedule the loadrunner scripts to run every night with 100 vusers. Could someone help me out how can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Amit

Answer (score 0):

Use the AT command with WLRUN command line.....or better yet use the scheduler in Performance Center to schedule your test to run at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the LR scheduler to work most of the time. But a very few number of times I've seen the scheduled time come and go and LR just missed it. Maybe a race condition? I don't know. it was infrequent enough that I never chased it down.

But I would try what James recommended, the AT Command.